# Why does the Spanish Military Medical Corps use the Amalfitan Cross?

Tags: military, spain, heraldry

The [Cuerpo Militar de Sanidad](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cuerpo_Militar_de_Sanidad) of the [Spanish Armed Forces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spanish_Armed_Forces) uses the Amalfitan Cross (often known as the [Maltese Cross](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maltese_cross)) in its emblem.  Why?

[image: Cuerpo Militar de Sanidad]

According to [Paloma Garrido González](https://www.elconfidencialdigital.com/articulo/defensa/defensa-elimina-corona-cruz-malta-vestimenta-militares-sanidad/20211005171031283183.html), the Cross was first introduced in 1931, but only in the 1990s, when the medical corps of the various branches of the [Spanish Armed Forces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spanish_Armed_Forces) were merged into a single corps, did the Cross become the emblem of Spanish military medicine:

> Fue autorizada en 1931 sobre el uniforme. Aunque no fue hasta 1990 cuando nació la Sanidad Militar unificada como se conoce a día de hoy, la cual se vio obligada a hacer grandes cambios de adaptación. Fue en esa década en la que se estableció la Cruz de Malta como seña de identidad propia para el Cuerpo.

However, this does not explain why the Cross was introduced in 1931.

Answer (score 7):

> En concreto, el emblema que identifica a este cuerpo es la Cruz de
> Malta, un símbolo que identifica al personal militar sanitario desde
> que en el siglo XII la utilizara la Orden de Malta, una orden
> religiosa nacida en el marco de las cruzadas y **que desarrollaba
> actividades hospitalarias y militares**.
>
> [Source](https://www.redaccionmedica.com/secciones/sanidad-hoy/la-cruz-de-malta-unico-emblema-de-la-sanidad-en-el-ambito-militar-3822)

So, it was adopted to honor the Order of Malta, because that order was considered the combination of military and healthcare activities.

Symbols for the army are quite arbitrary. Since [2021](https://www.elconfidencialdigital.com/articulo/defensa/defensa-elimina-corona-cruz-malta-vestimenta-militares-sanidad/20211005171031283183.html), doctors in the *Cuerpo Militar de Sanidad* use a caduceous, for example.

Comment: Thank you. You may want to cite this [post](https://www.facebook.com/permalink.php?story_fbid=pfbid0wcRYDzWH7cX78e5y2FziNZFZ6ndaqreETBeqtLUTAaD9w8c4wWaK1wZZYo1wEhPel&id=597895003590521&__xts__%5B0%5D=68.ARBo6erm8meeHxevmti2eiqaqY87lviaftcCngZajIxdk50y-DTUmwri8rpkHEPxG2__nZyQDPu5QMzAWKBgV5x1gK7D9axx2udcwN2MD2TmFiA4UiSvmtTEWXDRK4sLOQFTsf4lv901rsTkxJJb0MEyAAYRcmw0rHHThJsWlbg_hJ6Q-e3Q0iJ9VTLLVZ4QJGGub760jxSbH_nHhKKFNjZ6DNSWZRXmFSjvktZJO8b5U1IPid9Sfi4VnXCsyAwateSJ1t56IiI3dDb6m3RD_0Yh4CbONtBsi5uRQpZ9PRVwlik&__tn__=-R), too